# Bizarre behavior from Google Chrome with Anchor Links?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

Okay, I'm working on a making a responsive site with an off-canvas accordion menu and a auto-hiding navigation bar for mobile (max-width: 949px).  And it's coming along pretty well.  I've set it up so that clicking on the site canvas, the 'close button' or a sub-menu link closes the menu.  And everything transitions fine.  BUT if we click on an anchor link that points to anchor points on the page (e.g. the "policies", or "directions" anchor etc) it pushes the canvas to the left to where's it's almost totally off screen.
[image]
At first I thought this was some vendor prefix issue with my transitions but the transitions are totally fine as long as it's not triggered by an anchor.

The problem only occurs if

1. In Chrome (I've tested Firefox and IE, it may be happening in other WebKit broswers)
2. When the screen width is around less than 350px
3. When clicking on an embedded anchor.

http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/BNqJVX Here's a Code Pen.
I'm just toggling classes to push everything over 300px

```
  $('#closeButton, #site-canvas, nav li li').click(function() {
  $('#drawer').removeClass('show-nav');
  $('#nav-icon').removeClass('open');
  $("nav li.gotsMenus").removeClass("showSub");  });
```

CSS

```
#drawer.show-nav, #drawer.show-nav ~ #site-canvas, #drawer.show-nav ~ #menuHeader {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
  transform: translateX(300px);
}
```

Anyway, any ideas why this is happening or how to fix it?  I really don't think there's a problem with my code or the transitions, I think it's some bug in Chrome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue goes away if I change

```
#site-canvas {
//other styles
position: relative;
}
```

to

```
#site-canvas {
//other styles
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

I would still really like to know why I got this funky behavior and only in Chrome though :/